# Maven release plugin property updateVersionsToSnapshot not applied

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to make a branch and set the maven version on the branch to a non-snapshot version.

When doing this in interactive mode everything works out fine. But when running in batch mode the version on the branch will end in the -SNAPSHOT even though I provide the ["updateVersionsToSnapshot=false" property](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/branch-mojo.html#updateVersionsToSnapshot).

I run the following maven goal:

```
mvn release:branch -B -DreleaseVersion=1.3 -DupdateVersionsToSnapshot=false 
-DremoteTagging=false -DsuppressCommitBeforeBranch=true 
-DbranchName=generated/release_1.3 -DupdateBranchVersions=true 
-DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -Dusername=myUserName
```

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards 
Trym

Comment: I have this issue.  Apparently it's a 5 year old bug that they just never fixed :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe seems to be documented in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-959

There is a suggested patch in that ticket (which I haven't tested).  The team that works on the maven release-plugin hasn't picked up the ticket yet (at the time of writing).